# Scroll release to top automatically when list is pulled down in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am creating a panel and adding a list in it. On a service response the store is set for the list. Here's the code.

```
Ext.define('PACP.view.PriceChecker', {
    extend : 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.dataview.List'],
    xtype : 'pricechecker',
    config : {
//        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
//                flex: 1,
                xtype: 'list',
                id: 'categoriespanel',
                cls: 'usersList',
                storeId: 'categoriesStore',
                emptyText: '</pre>' +
                    '<div class="notes-list-empty-text">No User Found.</div>' +
                    '<pre>',
                itemTpl: Ext
                    .XTemplate('<div>{item}</div>')
            }
        ]
    }});
```

Now, the scroller is causing problem. When I drag down to see the records and release my thumb, scroller automatically gets to the top position. How can I resolve this issue?

I have checked vbox layout with flex as well but no success. On a painted event, if I load the data, it works but after painted or at a webservice response, it doesn't work. Or If I navigate to child view and then get to this view, then scroller works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try after set list confing "scrollToTopOnRefresh: false"